# Python - Search for occurances within text

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I have a list of phrases. I need to check if part of these phrases appear in a big block of text.

e.g.

- `Marshmallows are delicious and warm`
- `Giant unicorns sign wonderful melodies of the imminent apocalypse`
- `The wizards assaulted the fort, but forgot their spell books at home!`

Block of text is:

`Marshmallows are delicious. I've been snacking on them while the wizards assaulted the fort. The unicorns sign wonderful melodies of those who forgot their spell books at home. [...]`

---

Extra note:

I can't rely on splitting by stop words e.g. "and", "or" and punctuation.

---

Any ideas regarding libraries and/or strategies?

Thanks :)

Comment: What about the `in` operator?  `"oba" in "foobar"` is true, for example.

Comment: How do you define 'part'? One word? Two?

Answer (score 1):

You could create 'parts' of each phrase in descending order of length, then find these parts in the block of text.

e.g.

```
>>> text = "Marshmallows are delicious. I've been snacking on them while the wizards assaulted the fort. The unicorns sign wonderful melodies of those who forgot their spell books at home."
>>> phrase='Giant unicorns sign wonderful melodies of the imminent apocalypse'
>>> words = phrase.split()
>>> parts = list()
>>> for length in range(len(words),3,-1): #Assuming a part is atleast 3 words
    for start in range(0,len(words)-length + 1):
        parts.append(' '.join(words[start:start+length]))
>>> #A step of -1 ensures the list is sorted in a decreasing order of length.
>>> parts
['Giant unicorns sign wonderful melodies of the imminent apocalypse', 'Giant unicorns sign wonderful melodies of the imminent', 'unicorns sign wonderful melodies of the imminent apocalypse', 'Giant unicorns sign wonderful melodies of the', 'unicorns sign wonderful melodies of the imminent', 'sign wonderful melodies of the imminent apocalypse', 'Giant unicorns sign wonderful melodies of', 'unicorns sign wonderful melodies of the', 'sign wonderful melodies of the imminent', 'wonderful melodies of the imminent apocalypse', 'Giant unicorns sign wonderful melodies', 'unicorns sign wonderful melodies of', 'sign wonderful melodies of the', 'wonderful melodies of the imminent', 'melodies of the imminent apocalypse', 'Giant unicorns sign wonderful', 'unicorns sign wonderful melodies', 'sign wonderful melodies of', 'wonderful melodies of the', 'melodies of the imminent', 'of the imminent apocalypse']
>>> for part in parts:
    if part.lower() in text.lower(): #for case insensitivity
        found = part
        break

>>> found
'unicorns sign wonderful melodies of'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Xapian for storing searchable information and retrieving it (results = results!) as well as Levenshtein distance algorithms for which there are several modules for out there.